# Redefine folder structure of document library with metadata

Tags: sharepoint, moss, metadata, document

I have a problem in my sharepoint document library structure. Currently the document library consiste of folder sub-folder structure to store a document categorywise. Now our client want to redefine this folder structure with a metadata structure.

Can any one tell me how can I use metadata instade of folder sub folder structure..?

any related articles or links will be appriciated.

Thanks

Sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated, you need to use columns for the metadata, preferably through a new Content Type. After creating this Content Type, you need to attach it to the library and convert all documents to it. Lastly, you also need to modify the views of the library, e.g. depending on your metadata you might only want to display certain columns or filter them.

There is an excellent whitepaper from Microsoft on Content Types available here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262729.aspx

You can also read more about content type planning on Technet:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262735.aspx

And here's some info about Views:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA100215771033.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You must define columns for the metadata fields you want to have, create a content type that includes these columns, and assign this content type to your documents.

You might also change the default view of your document library, or create a new view, to make the new metadata columns visible.